# Excess pressure through a thick surface

Tags: pressure, surface-tension

Consider a sphere of Surface tension **T**, with inner radius **r** and thickness **d**. If the external pressure is *P*, what is the pressure inside such a sphere?

While dealing with bubble, we consider the boundary region to be quite thin. And excess pressure comes out to be:
**4T/r**

But if we were to account for the thickness of a sphere as well what would be the change in result?

Comment: I'm not sure that surface tension is the right way to think about a thick wall, since by definition it's not a "surface".

Comment: What other factors would affect the pressure difference?